# publish_actions permission errors

Tags: facebook, permissions, oauth

I'm trying to create an app with custom actions so I've added "publish_actions" to the list of permissions requested with the access token. My test user that doesn't currently use the app can't get an access token, I get an opaque error. see

[image: http://imgur.com/DPwNP]

I saw other posts about people changing their app to "Games" to work around problems with "publish_actions" but that has made no difference whatsoever. As soon as I remove "publish_actions" from the scope, my test user can get an access token fine but when it tries to post a custom action, the response is OAuthException error "(200#) Requires extended permission: publish_actions"

Some clarity on how one can develop and test custom actions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

It turns out that the problem was not having an aggregation with sample save configured under "App" > "App Name" > "Auth Dialog" in the 'Aggregation Previews' section. Once that was done, it worked. Unfortunately, Facebook's error provided no indication that that was the problem or that neglecting to configure the 'Aggregation Preview' will make the publish_actions permission fail. This looks like a bug on the Facebook side.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me too. I had trouble getting the aggregation preview working too, adding a "Preview Action" kept failing, but eventually it worked. Very buggy, but glad it is working.

Comment: I'm still having trouble. Facebook was reporting problems with my aggregations earlier, but that went away -- now I can't get publish_actions for any users, even developers.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting "message: "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions" too, and am not too sure what its referring to as it was working earlier.

Comment: I had the same problem. I tried creating an Aggregation Preview, deleting my app from my (personal) account settings, disabling and enabling the enhanced auth dialog in the app's advanced settings and trying again. Like everyone has said so far, this is very buggy and doesn't work as expected.

Comment: This one fixed it for me as well. The preview actions are needed for the moment facebook authenticates your app. It uses the sample data to show a preview to user how the action will look in their timeline

Comment: I am only able to post activities to the user that created the application. Posting as a developers or tester yields the above `Requires extended permission: publish_actions` error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I had done some tests using the Open Graph Test User and, therefore, this test user had accepted the app.

After that, I added "publish_actions" to the list of permissions. However, as the test user had already accepted the app, it wasn't asking again for authorisation.

To solve this, go to settings > apps and delete your app (while you're logged in as the test user).

Next time you run the app, it should ask again for authorisation.